# Magento - How do youretrieve a Product Attribute in the SIDEBAR?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

How would you go about retrieving Product Attributes in the sidebar?

I have edited my Catalog.xml like so:

```
<default>
<reference name="right">
<block type="core/template" template="callouts/right_template.phtml"/>
</reference>
</default>
```

and with my product attribute named “sidebar”, i have placed this code inside of the above referenced template file:

```
<?php echo $_product->getSidebar() ?>
```

It is pulling the content into the sidebar fine, (tested by using plain text), but the code used to retrieve the attribute is giving me a "**Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeName() on a non-object”**.  I’m assuming this is a scoping issue?

(This code worked fine in pulling the attribute when it was inside of “view.phtml")

Comment: Joe, Please add the code of the right_template.phtml to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The callout block doesn't have access to the product object, try changing:

```
<?php echo $_product->getSidebar() ?>
```

and use this instead:

```
<?php 
    $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if($_product){
      echo $_product->getSidebar();
    } 
?>
```

Notice this will only work in the product page.

Cheers!